# selecting **rows** of data according to their source

Tags: r

The dataset I'm working with has 13 columns with the following headers (bold), and 302 rows : **id:** 001, 002,..., 302), **source_code:** : AAA, BBB, CCC, **date**,**day**, **month**, **year**, **time**,**hour**, **minute**, **second**,**latitude**, **longitude**, **inscriptions:** NA, 1 or 0.

I have a script that creates density maps using this dataset, however, I want to be able to use filters that select the data I want the maps to include and exclude.

***example 1:*** I want to ONLY select the data with **source_code** : AAA  ( and name this selection of data: *data_A*)

***example 2:*** I want to ONLY select the data with **source_codes** AAA and BBB, and exclude CCC (and name this: *data_AB* )

***example 3:*** I want to ONLY select the data where **inscriptions** = 1 (name this: data_in1)

I am assuming these filters will have to be run  *before*  running the script to create each map.

I am new using Rstudio and this platform to ask questions, so sorry beforehand if this explanation is vague!

**Thank you!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data set is named `dataset` try

```
i1 <- dataset$source_code == 'AAA'
i2 <- dataset$source_code == 'BBB'
j <- dataset$inscriptions == 1

data_A <- dataset[i1, ]
data_AB <- dataset[i1 | i2, ]
data_in1 <- dataset[j, ]
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use i1, i2, j? or any letters can be used? Thank you so much for responding so quickly

Comment: @neussegura Any letters can be used. I used `i1` and `i2` because they were both related to the same `source_code` column.